# Which method is faster, express : Server-side rendering vs client-side rendering

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs

What I would like to know is, how do you built your web application? I'm really confuse as which method should I use for my project.

Already decided which technologies to choose.

1) Node.js and express as its Framework

2) MongoDB

3) React + Flux

But the problem right now, should I use method **(A)** or method **(B)**

Method **(A)** - Serverside rendering for HTML

```
app.get('/users/', function(request, respond) {
     var user = "Jack";
     respond.render("user", { user: user });
});
```

Method **(B)** - Clientside rendering for HTML

```
 app.get('/users/', function(request, respond){ 
       var user = "Jack";
       respond.json({ user: user });
    });
```

Method A will render the HTML from the server and as well as the data.

Method B will just respond the data that is needed for the client which is React.js, so that it could manipulate the data.

My concern, is which method should I use? most startups use which method?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're going to build an app using React, you should follow the Flux pattern.

Comment: Woops, didn't read Express on the title. Not too familiar with Express so might be different.

Comment: generally speaking, rendering more on the client side and doing less on your own servers is preferred.  But only so much can be rendered on the client-side, and it would be difficult to answer your question about what most startups do without specifying the type of startup.

Comment: If you do client-side rendering, you will need to do a parallel path for server-side rendering (of the same content) for search engines.

Comment: Client-side rendering is more scalable (since it uses the client CPU for some of the work and can likely do more efficient template caching) and is likely faster over slow links (less to download). Server-side rendering might compete for speed if the server is fast, lightly loaded and the link speed is fast.

Comment: Worth reading [Leaving JSPs in the dust: moving LinkedIn to dust.js client-side templates](https://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/leaving-jsps-dust-moving-linkedin-dustjs-client-side-templates) and [What are the pros and cons of client-side rendering](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-client-side-rendering).

Answer (score 6):

It's not an either/or proposition.

React is a client side framework. You have to render on the client side. The question is whether to render on the server side *in addition* to rendering on the client side.

The answer? If you can, YES!

You will get SEO benefits and an initial performance boost by rendering on the server side. But you will still have to do the same client side rendering.

I suggestion googling "isomorphic react" and doing some reading. Here is one article on the subject.
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/04/react-to-the-future-with-isomorphic-apps/

Comment: to note: "Isomorphic React" in regards to sever-side rendering React is now referred to as "Universal React"

Answer (score 5):

Well, it really depends on which vision you have on the modern web, and what you are willing to do.

Will you prefer to let your users wait, displaying a loader while data are loaded asynchronously, or will you prefer to keep your users busy as long as you can ?

Here are different articles that will help you clear your mind and be aware of the different advantages that you can have by doing server-side rendering, client-side rendering having multiple issues.

You can see this post from Twitter blog saying they improve their initial page load by 1/5th to what they had before, by moving the rendering to the server:

https://blog.twitter.com/2012/improving-performance-on-twittercom

An other article, this time from airbnb, describing the issues you can have with client-side rendering itself:

http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/

There is also an other interesting article talking about client-side/server-side rendering, bringing a debate on when should we use / not use server-side or client-side rendering and why:

https://ponyfoo.com/articles/stop-breaking-the-web

And to finish, I can give you two more link more focused on react, and describing in which way server-side rendering should be helpful for your case:

https://www.terlici.com/2015/03/18/fast-react-loading-server-rendering.html

http://reactjsnews.com/isomorphic-javascript-with-react-node/

Now, about what you SHOULD do, it's a matter of what you exactly need  to do, to my opinion, but basically, you can do both at the same time (client-side AND server-side), to have the best user experience.

This concept is called "isomorphic javascript" and it is getting more and more popular these days.

Comment: A possible counter-argument to the case you make: [Leaving JSPs in the dust: moving LinkedIn to dust.js client-side templates](https://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/leaving-jsps-dust-moving-linkedin-dustjs-client-side-templates).  Your performance may also depend upon exactly how you implement client-side templating.

Comment: Yes I guess so, judging by the many different way you can actually implement client-side rendering, or "isomorphic" applications.

Comment: I read most of the links that you shared, it really opens my mind about both but , since server-side rendering is fast, do i need to duplicate my codes for the API if i want to go mobile?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question; Are you talking about mobile hybrid app  ? Or native iOS/Android application ?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest architecture is to just do dynamic html rendering on the server, with no Ajax, and with a new HTML page requested for pretty much any client click. This is the 'traditional' approach, and has pros and cons.

The next simplest is to serve completely static html+js+css (your React app) to the client, and make XMLHttpRequest calls to webservices to fetch the required data (i.e. your method B).

The most complex but ideal approach (from a performance and SEO perspective) is to build an 'isomorphic' app that supports both approaches. The idea is that the server makes all the necessary WS calls that the client would make and renders the initial page that the user has visited (which could be a deep-linked part of the application), a bit like option A but using React to do the rendering, and then passes control to the client for future DOM updates. This then allows fast incremental updates to the page via web-service calls as the user interacts (e.g. just like B). Navigation between different 'pages' at this point involves using the History API to make it look like you're changing page, when actually you are just manipulating the current page using web-services. But you you then did a browser refresh, your server would send back the full HTML of the current page, before passing control to client-side React again. There are lots of React+Flux+Node examples of this approach available online, using the different flavours of Flux that support server-side rendering.

Whether that approach is worthwhile depends on your situation. It probably makes sense to start using approach B (you can share the your HTTP API between mobile apps and websites), but use a Flux architecture that supports server-side rendering and keep it in mind. That way, if you need to improve the performance of initial page loads, you have the means to do it.